# Scroll to an element after a click with slide down in jQuery

Tags: jquery, scroll, slidedown

I was looking how to scroll into next element like this:

http://www.grittirollo.it/

Click those big letters and it does scroll to current element after of click and slide down effect.

There is my attempt: (JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d272P/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="head1">Click</div>
<div id="child1">Content</div>

<br/>

<div id="head2">Click</div>
<div id="child2">Content</div>

<br/>

<div id="head3">Click</div>
<div id="child3">Content</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#head1{width: 400px; height: 40px; background: orange;}
#head2{width: 400px; height: 40px; background: red;}
#head3{width: 400px; height: 40px; background: purple;}

#child1{width: 300px; height: 700px; background: green; display: none;}
#child2{width: 300px; height: 700px; background: cyan; display: none;}
#child3{width: 300px; height: 700px; background: pink; display: none;}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#head1').click(function() {
  $('#child1').animate({
    opacity: 'toggle',
    height: 'toggle'
  },
  {
    duration: 750,
    specialEasing: {
      width: 'linear',
      height: 'easeInOutQuad'
    },
  }
  );
});

$('#head2').click(function() {
  $('#child2').animate({
    opacity: 'toggle',
    height: 'toggle'
  },
  {
    duration: 750,
    specialEasing: {
      width: 'linear',
      height: 'easeInOutQuad'
    },
  }
  );
});

$('#head3').click(function() {
  $('#child3').animate({
    opacity: 'toggle',
    height: 'toggle'
  },
  {
    duration: 750,
    specialEasing: {
      width: 'linear',
      height: 'easeInOutQuad'
    },
  }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JQuery ScrollTo](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo) should do the trick

**Edit**

After reviewing the sample site, I realise that [JQuery UI accordian](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion) might be the better option.

Comment: Well... i tried to test with ScrollTo... it didn't scroll to current element. There an updated fiddle (including scrollTo.js url) if you can see it:  http://jsfiddle.net/d272P/2/   Did i mistake :(?

Comment: I discovered about the options for jQuery UI accordion it has autoscroll, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this functionality can be achived by using jquery accordion

check the link http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/